# How do I get the code to always select the latest file within a JSON file, then retrieve a specific value

Tags: python, json

I don't want to change the code each quarter/year. How can I transform my function so it simply selects the latest file and retrieves a specific value - so in the example below, it would be the ['2020-12-31'] that is altered. Thank you

```
def freeCashFlow():
    for r in range(len(cleanstockdata2)):
        try:
            if (cleanstockdata2[r]['Financials']['Cash_Flow']['yearly']['2020-09-30']["freeCashFlow"]) in ['0','',None]:
                print (0)
            else:
                print (cleanstockdata2[r]['Financials']['Cash_Flow']['yearly']['2020-09-30']["freeCashFlow"])
        
         except KeyError:
             print (0)
```

[image]

Comment: Well I had been trying with:
list_of_files = glob.glob(‘jsonfile') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
latest_file
But as this was rubbish, I didn’t see the point of adding it. I apologise if my question has upset you mate. Just trying to learn. Have a nice weekend

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, nor it is it a place to have research, design or coding work done for you, mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the values in the json to datetime objects and just take the max of them, for instance:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
date_list = [dt.strptime(key, '%Y-%m-%d') for key in cleanstockdata2[r]['Financials']['Cash_Flow']['yearly'].keys()]
max_date = dt.strftime(max(date_list), '%Y-%m-%d')
desired_value = cleanstockdata2[r]['Financials'][max_date]["freeCashFlow"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help boss!